# sumtr on cells formatted as currency

Tags: jquery

I am using [sumtr](https://github.com/DLarsen/jquery-sumtr) to sum up a column but I'd like to be able to calculate the sum from a column that's formatted for currency.

```
$('#Cart').sumtr({
    readValue: function (e) { return Number(parseFloat(e.data('val'))
                             .replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, "")); },
    formatValue: function (val) { return formatCurrency(val); }
});
```

If I remove the `readValue` above then the code works fine, it totals up a column that does not have a currency symbol; I'm using the `formatCurrency()` method to display the total formatted with a currency symbol.
However if the column (with class "sum") is already formatted with currency then `sumtr` doesn't work with the values. So I've tried to get the `readValue` function to strip out anything but Numbers, but nothing is returned.

This is a part of the table sumtr is working on

```
<tr>
    <td>Adrobupicator</td>
    <td class="currency">&#163;700.01</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="sum currency">700.01</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>A1 Product 2</td>
    <td class="currency">&#163;36.28</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="sum currency">36.28</td>
</tr>
<tfoot>
    <tr class="summary">
        <td colspan="3">Cart Total</td>
        <td class="currency"></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using `e.data('val')`, it implies that you have set soem data vals on the td which I don't think you have done?

So you could either parse the td html like so:

```
$('#myTable').sumtr({
    readValue : function(e) { return parseFloat(e.html().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, "")); },
    formatValue : function(val) { return '$' + val; },
});
```

OR you can use `e.data('val')` if you have set the data. Then you wouldn't even need the regex. Either use data-attributes:

```
<tr>
    <td class="currency" data-val="700.01">&#163;700.01</td>
</tr>
```

or set the data explicitly using jQuery:

```
$("#yourtd").data("val", 700.01);
```